# styleUrls not being loaded in angular2 ChildComponent (RC5)

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In my angular 2 (RC5) project, I have a number of components which all work fine, however, I have added a submodule which works fine except for the `styleUrl` property of its childComponent. If I use the same url path in the `tutorial` (submodule's root component) then the styles are applied. If I add the exact same path to the `chapter` (submodule's child component) then the styles aren't applied?

There are no 404 coming through in the blogs and chrome's dev tools don't show `chapter.css` as a source, or something present on network.

Here you can see the component causing me the issue:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chapter',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css']
})
export class chapterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  private content: string = '';

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var that = this;
      var _url = './chapter/' + params['id'] + '.html';
      $.ajax({
        url: _url,
        success: function (result) {
          that.content = result;
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`chapter.css` isn't being picked up... You can see my project files here:

```
      |-- error.html',
      |-- index.html',
      |-- app',
          |-- app.component.ts',
          |-- app.module.ts',
          |-- app.routes.ts',
          |-- main.ts',
          |-- home',
          |   |-- home.component.ts',
          |   |-- home.css',
          |   |-- home.html',
          |-- tutorial',
              |-- tutorial.component.ts',
              |-- tutorial.css',
              |-- tutorial.html',
              |-- tutorial.module.ts',
              |-- tutorial.routes.ts',
              |-- chapter',
                  |-- chapter.component.ts',
                  |-- chapter.css',
                  |-- chapter.html',
```

Why does only this component not work... The only difference I can see is that this component is a child component, so maybe that has made a difference?

## Update:

As noted in the comments on the answers, using the path `./app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css` works in the tutorial component, but the exact same path doesn't work in the chapter component (which is a child component). I also added ViewEncapsulation but it didn't work...

Comment: Don't you think that it should be `/app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css`(exact)? OR `./chapter/chapter.css`

Comment: or try ./app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css

Comment: how are you building your project?  is webpack involved?

Comment: @Jim nope, no webpack. Plain vanilla typescript

Comment: @PankajParkar If you see the answer below, I tried that path and it works for the tutorial component, but not the child "chapter" component

Answer (score 11):

Try adding "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" to your parent component

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';  

   @Component({
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
     })
```

Comment: hmm, I'm afraid that doesn't make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html  This article has several different ways to approach the problem of relative paths with various module loaders.  That helped me reason about what was wrong when I had a similar problem (though I am using webpack, but it should not matter).

> The key lesson is to set the moduleId : module.id in the @Component decorator! Without the moduleId setting, Angular 2 will look for our files in paths relative to the application root.
>
> > And don’t forget the "module": "commonjs" in your tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

Change `styleUrls: ['app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css']` to `styleUrls: ['./app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css']`.

In case you were wondering, the `.` in `./app/tutorial/chapter/chapter.css` specifies the current directory.

Comment: If I use that path in the tutorial component, the styles work. If I use it in the chapter component, it doesn't ...